# how to find the adwords' click locations & timings

Tags: google-ads-api, pay-per-click

I've gone through the google/adwords dashboard again & again and found no means to figure out where exactly does the clicks happened and at what times.

I need to know the location of clicks (if possible city/ip) and the time of clicks. I believe there must be some way I'm missing, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this article](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2453994?hl=en&ref_topic=3122882); it explains how to get the geographic data for your campaigns. Though, it would not give you IP / timestamp for each click.